# SPARQL recursive ancestor query

Tags: sparql

I'm stuck with a recursive query in SPARQL, I cant wrap my head around it. I want to get all ancestors of an instance "`a`" (`a hasParent b, b hasParent c, c hasParent d`) so the result would be "`b, c ,and d`" if instance is "`a`".

Any ideas how to construct the linked part where parent has a parent which has another parent? (The depth of the recursion is not known)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [SPARQL property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) and operator **`+`**.

```
SELECT *
{ <a> <hasParent>+ ?ancestor }
```

Comment: Is the order of the result defined in any way?  Is it guaranteed to be always exactly `b, c, d` ?

Comment: The order is not defined.